# c++ отправляется и второй cin

Tags: c++, cin

Изучаю С++ и пишу тупой калькулятор. Возникла какая-то фигня, когда я ввожу 1 число, нажимаю Enter, то отправляется и второе число.

Ниже привел код:

```
// Учу с++.cpp : Этот файл содержит функцию "main". Здесь начинается и заканчивается выполнение программы.
//

#include <iostream>
#include <dos.h>
// Избегаем кода std:: через using namespace std
using namespace std;
int add(char num1, char num2)
{
    return (int)num1 + (int)num2;
}
int min(char num1, char num2)
{
    return (int)num1 - (int)num2;
}
int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    char num1;
    char num2;
    char mode;
    cout << "Число 1: ";
    cin >>  num1;
    cout << "\nЧисло 2: ";
    cin >> num2;
    cout << "\n1: +\n2: -\nВведите режим:";
    cin >> mode;
    if (mode == '1') {
        int result = add(num1, num2);
        cout << "\n" + result;
    }
    else if (mode == '2') {
        int result = min(num1, num2);
        cout << "\n" + result;
    }
}

// Запуск программы: CTRL+F5 или меню "Отладка" > "Запуск без отладки"
// Отладка программы: F5 или меню "Отладка" > "Запустить отладку"

// Советы по началу работы 
//   1. В окне обозревателя решений можно добавлять файлы и управлять ими.
//   2. В окне Team Explorer можно подключиться к системе управления версиями.
//   3. В окне "Выходные данные" можно просматривать выходные данные сборки и другие сообщения.
//   4. В окне "Список ошибок" можно просматривать ошибки.
//   5. Последовательно выберите пункты меню "Проект" > "Добавить новый элемент", чтобы создать файлы кода, или "Проект" > "Добавить существующий элемент", чтобы добавить в проект существующие файлы кода.
//   6. Чтобы снова открыть этот проект позже, выберите пункты меню "Файл" > "Открыть" > "Проект" и выберите SLN-файл.
```

В консоли я ввожу первым число 10, потом нажимаю Enter, и вижу такую картину:

```
Число 1: 10
Число 2:
1: +
2: -
Введите режим:
```

Хотя я поле `Число 2` не оставлял пустым, консоль сама оставила его пустым. Я думаю это из за скорости С++ и он думает что я оставил поле пустым, пробовал задержку но задержка не работает.

Comment: Потому что `num1` и `num2` имеют тип `char`. Поэтому, вводятся символы а не числа, т.е., символы '1' и '0', соответственно.

Answer (score 0):

Подозреваю, что Вы хотите вводить числа как строки, я правильно понимаю? Тогда давайте по порядку.

Во-первых, тип `char` используется не для передачи чисел, а для передачи [отдельных символов](http://cppstudio.com/post/437/), т.е. в переменной данного типа может хранится лишь один ASCII-символ. Вместо этого типа можно либо спокойно использовать один из существующих целочисленных типов данных (`int`, `long`, `long long` и прочее с `unsigned` — подробнее [здесь](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/cpp/cpp/cpp-type-system-modern-cpp?view=msvc-170)), либо использовать тип `string`.

Допустим, мы используем строковый тип данных, тогда для его преобразования в тип `int` мы используем функцию [`stoi()` (либо `stol()`, либо `stoll()` с соответствующими изменениями)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol).

Наконец, в конце Вы выводите данные таким образом:

```cpp
int result = add(num1, num2);
cout << "\n" + result;
```

хотя на самом деле ничего из подобного не выведется. Чтобы нормально вывести два и более литерала через `<<`, нужно разделить КАЖДЫЙ из них `<<`:

```cpp
int result = add(num1, num2);
cout << "\n" << result; // можно ещё использовать endl вместо "\n"
```

Окончательно, работающий код будет выглядеть примерно вот так:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
int add(string num1, string num2)
{
    return stoi(num1) + stoi(num2);
}
int min(string num1, string num2)
{
    return stoi(num1) - stoi(num2);
}
int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    string num1;
    string num2;
    char mode;
    cout << "Число 1: ";
    cin >>  num1;
    cout << "\nЧисло 2: ";
    cin >> num2;
    cout << "\n1: +\n2: -\nВведите режим:";
    cin >> mode;
    if (mode == '1') {
        int result = add(num1, num2);
        cout << "\n" << result;
    }
    else if (mode == '2') {
        int result = min(num1, num2);
        cout << "\n" << result;
    }
}
/*
Число 1: 861

Число 2: 711

1: +
2: -
Введите режим:1

1572
*/
```